# goreleaser to only generate the changelog on GitHub

Tags: go, release, goreleaser

I am the current maintainer for the testcontainers-go project
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go .

This project is a library. It does not produce any binary or docker image. I would still like to use goreleaser and the GitHub Action to automate the release process.

I had a look around but I am not able to find the right configuration to only run goreleaser to generate the changelog.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it isn't.

However, you can generate the changelog using `git`:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --no-decorate --no-color tags/v1.0.0..tags/v1.1.0
```

This is pretty much what GoReleaser does underneath.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot. At the end this is the command I will use:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. At the end this is the command I will use:

```
git log $(git describe --abbrev=0)...$(git describe --abbrev=0 $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)^) --pretty=format:'* [%s]("http://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/commit/%H")' --reverse
```